# Ajax does not call c# function but it is success. How?

Tags: c#, ajax

I try to draw chart using google charts.
My code call c# through Ajax to retrieve data from database. The dubuger does not go to c# function but, it hit success function of ajax!

**Aspx:**

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
   google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawchart);

   function drawchart(dataValues) 
   {
      alert("drawing function");
      alert(Object.keys(dataValues).length);            //alert 3
      alert(Object.keys(dataValues)); // alert Message, StackTrace,ExceptionType

      alert(Object.values(dataValues)); // alert Authentication failed.,,System.InvalidOperationException

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

      data.addColumn('string', 'Column Name');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Column Value');

      for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
          data.addRow([dataValues[i].gender, dataValues[i].cnt]);
      }

      new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('myChartDiv')).draw(data, { title: "Google Chart in Asp.net using jQuery" });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        url: 'Default.aspx/getGenderCount1',
                        data: '{}',
                        success:
                            function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                                alert(data + "\t" + textStatus);
                                drawchart(data);
                            },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(errorThrown);
                            alert("Error loading data!");
                        }

                    });
        })

    </script>
```

The alerts look likes this:

```
[object Object] success 
drawing function
3
Message,StackTrace,ExceptionType Authentication
failed.,,System.InvalidOperationException 
drawing function 
1 
isTrusted
true
```

**c#:**

```
public Static List<ParticipantGender> getGenderCount1()
    {
        List<ParticipantGender> ListOfParticipantGender = new List<ParticipantGender>();
        var conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("getGenderCount", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rdr.HasRows)
                while (rdr.Read())
                {

                    ListOfParticipantGender.Add(
                     new ParticipantGender
                     {
                         cnt = rdr.GetValue(0).ToString(),
                         gender = rdr.GetValue(1).ToString(),

                     });
                }
        }
        catch 
        {


        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
        }

        return ListOfParticipantGender;
    }
```

i also try the following:

> public  string getGenderCount1() and return the result as :  var json
>   = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListOfParticipantGender); return json;

It draw the chart with "no data" . i figure out that When i debug "getGenderCount1" in c#, it does not debugged. But, when i put the code in the load function and trace the data coming from the database, it 100% right.
It seems like the ajax does not call the c# but it process the ajax success function!!!!

Comment: `Default.aspx/getGenderCount1` That is an odd looking URL.

Comment: @mjwills i didn't get your point!

Comment: ASP.NET WebForms returns status code 200 responses, which is considered a successful response by jQuery's ajax function, for just about everything which doesn't trigger a redirect. Anything else (30x redirects or actual error codes in the 400 or 500 range) would trigger the fail/error handler in the ajax function.

Comment: You can see the response headers (including the status code) in the Network tab of pretty much every brower's developer console. I would suggest verifying that.

Comment: Don't you need to use `[WebMethod]` attribute to decorate your method that you are calling from the client side? Have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179596/consume-net-web-service-using-jquery